# EMTEC 32gb flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, defragment, disk-cleanup

I have work pictures and videos on this and now when I go to use it it says to reformat it.  I dont know if I could recreate the data again:(  Prior to Windows 10, I was able to do a disk clean and I believe reformat on either it or a similar work drive and it was back working.

Any idea on how to do this now?  I know defrag is not recommended but this is a special event. I am at a loss without these files and really need a solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I was able to do a disk clean" - You would do this identically to how you did previously, but, doing so would make data recovery extremely tough.

Comment: Save all the files elsewhere and reformat.

Comment: Ramhound-I had a Windows 7 computer the other time, now I have Windows 10 and it doesnt allow you to, at least not that I know.

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik-I cannot access the files in order to save them.  I do realize I should have saved them to the SSD but kept putting it off:(